# PEAR Mail error suspected

Tags: php, email, pear

I am working on migrating a form processing script using the PEAR Mail.php library from one site to another within PHP5.
The script is pasted at the bottom fo this message.  Everything seems to be working fine. I don't get any PHP errors even with this in script:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

but the browser result points to a PEAR error state returned by PEAR:

```
"An email error has occurred..."
```

which is the result of this in the script:

```
if (PEAR::isError($mail2)) {
```

This said, I don't know how to find more details regarding this PEAR error.  Is there a way to turn on some sort of explicit error messaging by PEAR?

Any advice regarding the code below?

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Relies on PEAR Mail module!
require_once "Mail.php";

if (isset($_REQUEST['pdfName']) && isset($_REQUEST['pdfEmail'])) {
    $name    = $_REQUEST['pdfName'];
    $email   = $_REQUEST['pdfEmail'];
    $file    = $_REQUEST['pdfFile'];

    $host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net'; 
    $user = 'ot@domain.com';
    $pass = 'password';

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                         array ('host' => $host,
                                          'auth' => true,
                                          'username' => $user,
                                          'password' => $pass));

    $to = "info@domain.com";
    $Bcc = "dan@domain.com";
    $recipients = $to.", ".$Bcc;
    $from = "info@domain.com";
    $subject = "Document request on company.com";
    $body = "Hello Sales Team,

Name: $name
Email: $email

Requested the file: http://en.domain.com/docs/$file";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                            'To' => $to,
                            'Bcc' => $Bcc,
                            'Subject' => $subject);

    $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);


    $to = $email;
    $from = "info@domain.com";
    $subject = "company Your document is here";
    $body = "Hello $name,

The document you requested one http://www.domain.com can be found here: 
http://en.domain.com/docs/$file

Enjoy the information.

If you have questions, do not hesitate to contact us.
E-Mail: info@domain.com
Tel: +1 (000) 606 4000 (US office)

Kind regards
The company Team
www.domain.com

The information contained in this email is intended only for the use of the person or entity to whom it is addressed and may contain information that is confidential and maybe legally privileged and exempt from disclosure under applicable laws. If you read this message and are not the addressee, you are notified that use, dissemination, distribution or reproduction of this message is legally prohibited. If you have received this message in error, please notify us immediately and return the original message to us.";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                            'To' => $to,
                            'Subject' => $subject);
    $mail2 = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail2)) {
        //echo("<p>" . $mail2->getMessage() . "</p>");
        echo("<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='margin:10px 0 20px 10px;'>
<div style='margin:10px 0 2px 5px;color:#01578C;'>An email error has occurred.</div>
<div style='margin:0 0 20px 5px;'>Please provide a valid email address so we can send you a link to the requested document.</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align='left' valign='top' style='width: 350px;'><span style='padding-left:5px' >Please submit a new request.</span></td>
<td style='padding:2px 5px;'><div style='height:109px;'>&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>");
    } else {
        echo("<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='margin:10px 0 20px 10px;'>
<div style='margin:10px 0 2px 5px;color:#01578C;'>Your data were sent successfully.</div>
<div style='margin:0 0 20px 5px;'>A link to the requested document was sent to the email address you provided.</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align='left' valign='top' style='width: 350px;'><span style='padding-left:5px' >Enjoy the information.</span>
<P>
<br>
&nbsp;<A HREF=\"javascript:history.go(-2)\">Click here to go back to browsing company.com.
</td>
<td style='padding:2px 5px;'><img align='left' alt='' src='/docdown/index-files/whitepaper.jpg'/></td>
</tr>
");
    }

} else {
        echo("<tr>    
<td colspan='2' style='margin:10px 0 20px 10px;'>
<div style='margin:10px 0 2px 5px;color:#01578C;'>
An error has occurred.</div>
<div style='margin:0 0 20px 5px;'>Please provide a valid email address so we can send you a link to the requested document.</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>        
<td align='left' valign='top' style='width: 350px;'><span style='padding-left:5px' >Please submit a <A HREF=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\"> new request on the previous page.</a></span></td>    
<td style='padding:2px 5px;'><div style='height:109px;'>&nbsp;</div></td>    
</tr>");    
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got it right there, commented out.

```
echo("<p>" . $mail2->getMessage() . "</p>");
```

Answer (score -1):

OK - found it - this code does the trick very well:

```
 // Pear Mail error messaging
 if ($emailerror = PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 echo("<p><br><p><br>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>"); exit;
 }
```

Comment: You'd notice that it's already there in your code. You've commented it out.